# PHP Regex for rewriting part of URL in 404 script

Tags: php, regex, redirect

I have a php script handling URL's that are about to be redirected to 404.

How can I rewrite an URL like example.com/oldnonexistentcategory-actualproduct-**product_reviews-actualproduct.htm** to example.com/**product_reviews-actualproduct.htm** ?

Said another way - how do I remove everything between "example.com/" and "product_reviews" ?

The only consistent part of the URL is that it contains example.com and product_reviews. I've considered using preg_match/preg_replace but I'm very new at regex syntax.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what exactly needs to be rewritten?

Comment: Btw, your query is unsafe; it doesn't escape the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` well enough.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want to remove everything between / and product_reviews from the URL.
The tep_db_query function I'm using should escape the complete string correctly before doing anything with it at all (as far as I know unless just passing it to the function is unsafe by itself?)

Comment: The query you're passing is unsafe, so it's not possible the function will be able to correct that.

Comment: Will $the404url = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); fix it or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that would help; you should stop using `mysql_` though ;-)

Comment: I'm in the process of rewriting my db functions and I'm switching to mysqli.
Why was this marked as not a real question? 
"How can I use preg_match / preg_replace to rewrite an URL like example.com/oldnonexistentcategory-actualproduct-product_reviews-actualproduct.htm to example.com/product_reviews-actualproduct.htm ?" seems pretty specific to me?(Especially after the clarification)

Comment: As it stands now, the question is buried in other unrelated information; if the question is about replacing X with Y, *that* should be the only thing in the question, besides maybe some attempted code.

Comment: I just removed everything non-essential from the question.

Comment: Alright, I've voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your URL are based like that, don't use preg_match but explode which is faster and easier to use :

```
<?php

// ...

$explodedUrl = explode('-', 'oldnonexistentcategory-actualproduct-product_reviews-actualproduct.htm');

$redirectUrl = $explodedUrl[2].'-'.$explodedUrl[3];

echo $redirectUrl; // product_reviews-actualproduct.htm
```

But be careful, this suppose 2 things :

1. Your URL are always based on 4 parts, separated by "-":
   "`string-string-string-string.htm`"
2. A part of the slug "`string`"
       can't have a "-" char (Otherwise, the script will not work
       corretly).

**So make sure you don't have a slug with "-" char in a part**, not like that : `old-non-existent-category-actual-product-product-reviews-actual-product.htm`

If your URL can have more or less than 4 parts, and you always want the 2 last parts, you can make your script dynamic, it's easy :

```
$numberPart = count($explodedUrl);
$redirectUrl = $explodedUrl[$numberPart - 2].'-'.$explodedUrl[$numberPart - 1];
```

**EDIT:**

> Can I use explode to remove everything between / and product_reviews?

Absolutely !

```
$explodedUrl = explode('product_reviews-', 'oldnonexistentcategory-actualproduct-product_reviews-actualproduct.htm');
$redirectUrl = $explodedUrl[count($explodedUrl) - 1]; // Get string after "product_reviews-"
echo $redirectUrl; // actualproduct.htm

// So finally :
echo "example.com/product_reviews-".$redirectUrl; // example.com/product_reviews-actualproduct.htm
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough about what needs to be rewritten - the structure is /category-subcategory-possible_sub_sub-category-product_reviews- ...
The only consistent part of the URL will the that it contains -product_reviews-

Comment: The urls can contain dashes and extra subcategories so it probably won't work out of the box - maybe I could explode by -product_reviews instead of just the dash? Can I use explode to remove everything between / and product_reviews?